# How to support contextual implicit conversions of custom object in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, object, casting

I want to use named error codes within my app. This should ensure, that every developer does not confuse numeric-only error codes with other codes, and also reduces the time a developer needs to realize what the error code should represent.

Compare this example:

```
Function New() As Integer
    Return 0
End Function
```

with this example:

```
Function New() As Integer
    Return ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS
End Function
```

Of course, I could let the developers write like the following:

```
Function New() As Integer
    Return 0 ' ERROR_SUCCESS
End Function
```

However, the code above raises a pitfall when a developer updates the actual return code but forgets about the comment. Some developer look at the actual return code and some at the comment. I want to mitigate that confusion.

I come up the following class (extract):

```
Public Class ErrorCodes
    Private msName As String = Nothing
    Private miValue As Integer = 0

    Public Shared ReadOnly ERROR_SUCCESS As ErrorCodes = New ErrorCodes("ERROR_SUCCESS", 0)

    Private Sub New(ByVal psName As String, ByVal piValue As Integer)
        msName = psName
        miValue = piValue
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property [Name] As String
        Get
            Return msName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property [Value] As Integer
        Get
            Return miValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("[{0}]{1}", msName, miValue)
    End Function
End Class
```

Now I want to use this `ErrorCodes` class like in the following example:

```
Function New() As Integer
    Return ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS
End Function
```

As expected, I will produce an exception (type conversion) since the actual value I return is a instance of the class `ErrorCodes` instead of the generic data type `Integer`.

As you can see with the `ToString()` function, I let the class automatically/implicitly converts the instanced object into the generic data type `String`, when the class instance is assigned to a `String` typed variable.

**Is there a way to do the same with the generic data type `Integer` like I did with `ToString()`?**

I am using the .NET Framework 4.0, as for compatibility reasons with Windows XP SP3.

Another way to say what I want:

```
Dim stringVariable As String = ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS ' should be "[0]ERROR_SUCCESS".
Dim integerVariable As Integer = ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS ' should be 0.
```

I do not want to trigger *implicit conversion* warnings/errors, or to force the developer to typecast explicitly.

Comment: Could you just do "Return ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS.Value" ?

Comment: @the_lotus Would be the "last" resort. I try to find an implementation in which the deveoper has to type/read less.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be using an `Enum`. They have a numeric value, a text name and, if you want more, you can add a `Description` attribute.  You might [check this out](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?552547).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that with the use of Conversion Operators.
Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
  Public Class ErrorCodes
    Private msName As String = Nothing
    Private miValue As Integer = 0

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal ec As ErrorCodes) As String
        Return ec.ToString
    End Operator

    Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal ec As ErrorCodes) As Integer
        Return ec.Value
    End Operator

    Public Shared ReadOnly ERROR_SUCCESS As ErrorCodes = New ErrorCodes("ERROR_SUCCESS", 0)
    Public Shared ReadOnly ERROR_FAILED As ErrorCodes = New ErrorCodes("ERROR_FAILED", 1)

    Private Sub New(ByVal psName As String, ByVal piValue As Integer)
        msName = psName
        miValue = piValue
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property [Name] As String
        Get
            Return msName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property [Value] As Integer
        Get
            Return miValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("[{0}]{1}", msName, miValue)
    End Function
  End Class

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim em As String = ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS
    Dim ev As Integer = ErrorCodes.ERROR_SUCCESS
    Dim mm As String = String.Format("String: {0}, Value: {1}", em, ev)

    MsgBox(mm)
  End Sub
End Class
```

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-define-a-conversion-operator)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This, as jmcilhinney pointed out, uses Enums and the Description attribute.

Here is the class

```
'requires
'  Imports System.Reflection
'  Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class ErrorCodes
    Public Enum ErrCode 'these are the error codes
        'note that the codes should be unique
        <Description("Success")> ERROR_SUCCESS = 0
        <Description("Error A")> ERROR_A = 1
    End Enum

    Public Class InfoForErrCode
        Public TheDescription As String
        Public TheValue As Integer
        Public AsString As String
    End Class

    Public Shared Function Info(TheError As ErrCode) As InfoForErrCode
        Dim rv As New InfoForErrCode
        rv.TheDescription = GetDescription(TheError)
        rv.TheValue = TheError
        rv.AsString = TheError.ToString
        Return rv
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetDescription(TheError As ErrCode) As String
        Dim rv As String = ""
        Dim fi As FieldInfo = TheError.GetType().GetField(TheError.ToString())

        Dim attr() As DescriptionAttribute
        attr = DirectCast(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute),
                                                 False), DescriptionAttribute())

        If attr.Length > 0 Then
            rv = attr(0).Description
        Else
            rv = TheError.ToString()
        End If
        Return rv
    End Function
End Class
```

And here is how it can be used

```
    Dim foo As ErrorCodes.ErrCode = ErrorCodes.ErrCode.ERROR_SUCCESS
    Dim inf As ErrorCodes.InfoForErrCode = ErrorCodes.Info(foo)
    Stop 'examine inf
    foo = ErrorCodes.ErrCode.ERROR_A
    inf = ErrorCodes.Info(foo)
    Stop 'examine inf
```